# How to write epsilon in Xmgrace?

Tags: plot, xmgrace

In Xmgrace, the `var-epsilon` (the inverted-3 form) can be written as `\xe\f{}`.
I need to write the `epsilon` (the lunate form) in xmgrace.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `"\xÎ"` combination to get something that is similar to (but not exactly) a [lunate epsilon](https://graphemica.com/%CF%B5), but otherwise I am not aware of any other methods that can be used to directly input an `\epsilon` into xmgrace. Unfortunately, xmgrace is an old piece of software and does not have unicode support.

If you have no alternatives, I think that best course of action would be to generate an eps file and use [inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) or a similar software to directly edit the "right" epsilon in.

Comment: I tried to get a lunate epsilon but I could not, so I believe this answer is correct. Perhaps try some different plotting software.